# Pseudolocalization in CakePHP/2

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.4

I'm adapting an existing application to support several languages and I'd like to implement [pseudolocalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization), i.e. make localized strings:

```
<?php echo h(__('Edit program settings')); ?>
```

... stand out:

```
[!!! εÐiţ Þr0ģЯãm səTτıИğ§ !!!]
```

... so I can quickly spot omissions and detect potential layout problems.

Unless I'm wrong the feature is not builtin and there aren't third-party plugins. What are my chances?

I feel a sensible path would be to extend `I18n` and overwrite `I18n::translate()`. However I'm not specially familiar with CakePHP internals and I'm not sure about how to make `__()` and family use my extended class.

On the other side, functions in `lib\Cake\basics.php` are wrapped in `function_exists()` calls so I guess I could write my own versions...

I'd welcome any suggestion.

Comment: It may help if you'd describe your specific use case, and include some code for it.

Comment: @ndm Alright, I've edited the question.

Comment: I get the general idea of pseudo localization, but where and how exactly would you want to use it in your application specifically? Are you using an automated environment that performs GUI tests?

Comment: @ndm No, nothing as fancy. I just want to to display the strings on screen as usual to see them while I use the app. (I'm right now playing with `auto_prepend_file` to define i18n functions before CakePHP loads the original ones and it looks promising.)

Comment: I see... in that case overriding the translation functions to make them use custom translators, or directly create the required pseudo localization, seems like a reasonable, non-obstrusive solution.

Comment: I also have the impression that I could abuse `APP::$_classMap` to load my alternative `I18n` class...

Comment: Not sure, I mostly forgot how autoloading in 2.x works (for the better I guess :)), but I think the `App::uses()` call in the core would override possible modifications. I guess you could possibly ["override" the I18n class](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#overriding-classes-in-cakephp) at app level.

Comment: @ndm That's neat! I wonder if I can still use the base class to do 99% of the work so I don't need to maintain a full copy... Whatever, this is meant to be a dev tool -- I think it's running out of control!

Comment: Probably not, as you have to use the same class name, and PHP doesn't allow to reuse/redeclare class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal technique would be to be able to define a custom class:

```
class CustomI18n extends I18n {
    public static function translate($singular, $plural = null, $domain = null, $category = 6, $count = null, $language = null) {
    }
}
```

… and instruct CakePHP to use my custom class rather than the original. That would be coherent with e.g. the way view helpers work.

Unfortunately, I don't think it can't be done¹ because `$this->Html` inside a view is a dynamic property but `__()` contains a hard-coded class name: `I18n::translate($singular)`.

¹ <sub>Yes, [almost](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) [everything](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) can be done. You know what I mean :)</sub>

---

Since it's just a helper tool that's not meant for Production, you can always resort to a quick and dirty hack not really specific to CakePHP:

1. Rewrite into a file of your choice the functions from `lib\Cake\basics.php` you're interested in, typically the ones that start with underscore: `__()`, `_n()`, ...

   ```
   function __($singular, $args = null) {
       if (!$singular) {
           return;
       }
       $singular = pseudotranslation($singular); // <---------------------

       App::uses('I18n', 'I18n');
       $translated = I18n::translate($singular);
       if ($args === null) {
           return $translated;
       } elseif (!is_array($args)) {
           $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
       }
       return vsprintf($translated, $args);
   }
   ```

   Make sure you don't break `vsprintf` codes.
2. Use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) to load the file before CakePHP startup begins. Ideally, set it on in your development box.

This has the advantage of being unobtrusive. You can enable or disable `auto_prepend_file` quite easily or you can take care of that in your prepended script.

---

Alternatively, CakePHP allows to [override](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#overriding-classes-in-cakephp) most classes so you could copy `/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php` as `/app/Lib/I18n/I18n.php` and tweak `I18n::translate()` to your liking. However I find this less convenient: you still have to maintain a custom copy of a system file if you upgrade CakePHP and there's no simple mechanism to disable pseudolocalisation on runtime since CakePHP will always use the file when it's present.